# Translating Firebird SQL trigger to PG trigger/function

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert Firebird SQL trigger code to trigger/function in PG.

On the following I get a syntax error on ';' at "END;", I think I changed the rest correctly but can't figure out that syntax error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION purchase_q_ai0()
  RETURNS void as $$

    declare
    CB_QUANTITY integer;
    CB_QUANTITYONHAND integer;
    CB_BOT_ID keys;
    CB_ID keys;
    BOT_QUANTITY integer;
    BOT_QUANTITYONHAND integer;
    BOT_ID keys;
    TEMP_QUANTITY integer;

BEGIN
    /* Update cellarbook and bottle after INSERT
    quantitypurchase, quantityonhand, purchasevalueonhand and
    currentvalueonhand will be updated */
    if (new.quantity is Null) then
        TEMP_QUANTITY := 0;
    else
        TEMP_QUANTITY := new.quantity;

    /* get corresponding cellarbook info */
    select cellarbook.quantitypurchased, cellarbook.quantityonhand, cellarbook.fk_bottle_id, cellarbook.id
            from cellarbook
            where new.fk_cellarbook_id = cellarbook.id
            into cb_quantity, cb_quantityonhand, cb_bot_id, cb_id;

    if (CB_QUANTITY is null) then
        CB_QUANTITY := 0;
    if (CB_QUANTITYONHAND is null) then
        CB_QUANTITYONHAND := 0;

    /* get corresponding bottle info */
    select bottle.quantitypurchased, bottle.quantityonhand, bottle.id from bottle
           where bottle.id = cb_bot_id
           into bot_quantity, bot_quantityonhand, bot_id;

    if (BOT_QUANTITY is null) then
        BOT_QUANTITY := 0;
    if (BOT_QUANTITYONHAND is null) then
        BOT_QUANTITYONHAND := 0;

    /* update with new info */
    update cellarbook set cellarbook.quantitypurchased = (cb_quantity + temp_quantity),
                          cellarbook.quantityonhand = (cb_quantityonhand + temp_quantity),
                          cellarbook.purchasevalueonhand = (cellarbook.lastpurchaseprice * cellarbook.quantityonhand),
                          cellarbook.currentvalueonhand = (cellarbook.currentvalue * cellarbook.quantityonhand)
            where cellarbook.id = cb_id;
    update bottle set bottle.quantitypurchased = (bot_quantity + temp_quantity),
                      bottle.quantityonhand = (bot_quantityonhand + temp_quantity),
                      bottle.purchasevalueonhand = (bottle.lastpurchaseprice * bottle.quantityonhand),
                      bottle.currentvalueonhand = (bottle.currentvalue * bottle.quantityonhand)
           where bottle.id = bot_id;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Seems you are not properly closing `IF ELSE` block make sure that you've  closed using `END IF`

Comment: In addition to that  if this is a a trigger function then  `RETURNS trigger AS` instead of `RETURNS void as`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger function in `plpgsql` language always needs to return `trigger` and it needs a proper return statement as well. Otherwise you need to `END IF` your `IF` statements and restructure your `SELECT INTO` statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION purchase_q_ai0() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  CB_QUANTITY integer;
  CB_QUANTITYONHAND integer;
  CB_BOT_ID keys;
  CB_ID keys;
  BOT_QUANTITY integer;
  BOT_QUANTITYONHAND integer;
  BOT_ID keys;
  TEMP_QUANTITY integer;
BEGIN
  /* Update cellarbook and bottle after INSERT
     quantitypurchase, quantityonhand, purchasevalueonhand and
     currentvalueonhand will be updated */
  IF (NEW.quantity IS NULL) then
    TEMP_QUANTITY := 0;
  ELSE
    TEMP_QUANTITY := NEW.quantity;
  END IF;

  /* get corresponding cellarbook info */
  SELECT cb.quantitypurchased, cb.quantityonhand, cb.fk_bottle_id, cb.id
  INTO cb_quantity, cb_quantityonhand, cb_bot_id, cb_id
  FROM cellarbook cb
  WHERE NEW.fk_cellarbook_id = cb.id;

  IF (CB_QUANTITY IS NULL) THEN
    CB_QUANTITY := 0;
  END IF;
  IF (CB_QUANTITYONHAND IS NULL) THEN
    CB_QUANTITYONHAND := 0;
  END IF;

  /* get corresponding bottle info */
  SELECT b.quantitypurchased, b.quantityonhand, b.id
  INTO bot_quantity, bot_quantityonhand, bot_id
  FROM bottle b
  WHERE b.id = cb_bot_id;

  IF (BOT_QUANTITY IS NULL) THEN
    BOT_QUANTITY := 0;
  END IF;
  IF (BOT_QUANTITYONHAND IS NULL) THEN
    BOT_QUANTITYONHAND := 0;
  END IF;

  /* update with new info */
  UPDATE cellarbook SET
    quantitypurchased = cb_quantity + temp_quantity,
    quantityonhand = cb_quantityonhand + temp_quantity,
    purchasevalueonhand = lastpurchaseprice * quantityonhand,
    currentvalueonhand = currentvalue * quantityonhand
  WHERE id = cb_id;

  UPDATE bottle SET
    quantitypurchased = bot_quantity + temp_quantity,
    quantityonhand = bot_quantityonhand + temp_quantity,
    purchasevalueonhand = lastpurchaseprice * quantityonhand,
    currentvalueonhand = currentvalue * quantityonhand
  WHERE id = bot_id;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I leave it to you to repair the case of the internally declared variables (use of lowercase is recommended in PostgreSQL).

Incidentally, PostgreSQL does not know the `keys` data type by default. Unless you define that data type the code won't work. Is this perhaps something specific to Firebird, for use as a `PRIMARY KEY`? In that case it is most likely a 32-bit integer and you would use the `integer` data type in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Adding the 'end if's fixed my initial issue.  Thanks for the other pointers, will look into them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly use `END IF` in the following area

---

```
if (new.quantity is Null) then
    TEMP_QUANTITY := 0;
else
    TEMP_QUANTITY := new.quantity;
End if;
```

---

```
if (CB_QUANTITY is null) then
   CB_QUANTITY := 0;
if (CB_QUANTITYONHAND is null) then
   CB_QUANTITYONHAND := 0;
End if;
End if;
```

---

```
if (BOT_QUANTITY is null) then
    BOT_QUANTITY := 0;
if (BOT_QUANTITYONHAND is null) then
    BOT_QUANTITYONHAND := 0;
End if;
End if;
```

[**PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS)

Comment: Your code does not work. From the update documentation: "Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE tab SET tab.col = 1 is invalid." Also, it is SELECT ... INTO target FROM ... WHERE ....

Comment: @Patrick I just Added the `END IF` where it's necessary, BTW I don't get you

Comment: As you commented on the OP, a trigger needs to return a `trigger` object, it also needs a `RETURN NEW` statement, the `SELECT INTO` statements are wrong, as are the `UPDATE` statements. You missed these in the code you pasted.

Comment: @Patrick, the function is not changing the table the trigger will fire on it is updating two other tables, do I still have to return new?

Comment: @Werner, a trigger always has to `RETURN NEW` (or `OLD` in the case of a delete trigger) to signal that the operation can go ahead. If you do not return the correct type, the operation that fired the trigger will be rolled back. See the documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html